# How to construct the following table with title in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, pdftex, code

I would like to construct a table look like the picture below:

[image: wanted]

The code below represents my best attempt so far (the words in the table don't really mean anything):

```
\resizebox{9cm}{!} {
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{c}r} 
Model              & Linear Regression && MLE \\
\hline
fakedata50  & -1.037 & &4   \\
fakedata100 & -1.038 && 3  \\
fakedata500  & -0.7859 && 2 \\
fakedata5000  &-0.7742 && 2  \\
fakedata10000 &-0.7665&&o \\
fakedata100000 &-0.7206&&j \\
fakedata1000000 &-0.6939&&j \\
\end{tabular} }
```

However, I would like to center my table but the command `\centering` is not working.

Also, when I tried to enlarge my graph by changing the value in `\resizebox`, the font size increased as well, which is undesirable. Is there a way of increasing the font size proportionally to how much I enlarge my table?

Lastly, how can I typeset a title for my table?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When constructing tables, the [`booktabs`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/booktabs) package is your best friend; in your particular case, I'd also recommend the [`siunitx`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/siunitx) package to help with decimal alignment (of course, the package can do a lot more besides column alignment).

[image: screenshot]

The `S` column type takes an optional argument - this allows you to tweak each individual column; I have used `table-format=1.4` to detail that this column has `1` number *before* the decimal, and `4` numbers after it. You'll note that I had to enclose the column head in `{Linear Regression}` to 'escape' it from math mode and the decimal alignment routine.

Here's the complete code for you to play with.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=1.4]r}
    \toprule
    Model           & {Linear Regression} & MLE \\
    \midrule
    fakedata50      & -1.037              & 4   \\
    fakedata100     & -1.038              & 3   \\
    fakedata500     & -0.7859             & 2   \\
    fakedata5000    & -0.7742             & 2   \\
    fakedata10000   & -0.7665             & o   \\
    fakedata100000  & -0.7206             & j   \\
    fakedata1000000 & -0.6939             & j   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If you're wanting to make a 'title' for your `table`, then you should use the `caption` command; you will either have to put your `tabular` environment inside of a `table` environment, or otherwise use the `captionof` command from the `caption` package.

[image: screenshot with caption]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Your caption goes here}
    \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=1.4]r}
        \toprule
        Model           & {Linear Regression} & MLE \\
        \midrule
        fakedata50      & -1.037              & 4   \\
        fakedata100     & -1.038              & 3   \\
        fakedata500     & -0.7859             & 2   \\
        fakedata5000    & -0.7742             & 2   \\
        fakedata10000   & -0.7665             & o   \\
        fakedata100000  & -0.7206             & j   \\
        fakedata1000000 & -0.6939             & j   \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: does that matter if I am using \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart} ? and how to do the doulbe line on the top and bottom of the graph in latex?

Comment: @user3579282 no, it should be fine; it is typically best to provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) so that folks don't have to guess at your `documentclass`. you can get two horizontal lines by using `toprule` twice (personally, I wouldn't recommend it)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `table-format=-1.4`? Or may be `table-format=+1.4`? Or you did it on purpose?

Answer (score 4):

Even the standard `tabular` environment provides you with tools for adjusting the size of your table.  Most notably, the length `tabcolsep` adjusts the padding on the side of each column.  In my example, I needed to shrink it to make the table fit in the standard `\textwidth`, but in your case, you could increase its value.  Likewise, I changed the font size to `\small`, but one need not do that, unless space is an issue, or to maintain consistency throughout a document.

For vertical space, I use `\renewcommand\arraystretch{}` to stretch the space between table rows.  Once in an environment, `\centering` works just fine.  When using it outside of an environment, use `{\centering my table stuff \par}`.  The braces will limit the extent of the centering to just the embraced stuff.  And the `\par` is needed to activate the `\centering`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\twostack#1#2{\addstackgap{\stackanchor[0pt]{\strut#1}{\strut#2}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\tabcolsep 3pt
\caption{Chi-square analysis for data set Total Site 1}
\medskip\small
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
\hline
\hline
\textbf{Model} & \textbf{Parameters} & \textbf{Estimates} & 
  \textbf{\twostack{Chi-square}{statistic}} & 
  \textbf{P-value} & \textbf{Outcome} & \\
\hline
Geometric Series & $k$ & 0.129202 & 17019.3 & $<$0.001 & Reject\\
\twostack{Broken Stick}{(binned)} & - & - & 1430.72 & $<$0.001 & Reject\\
\twostack{Broken Stick}{(rank abundance)} & - & - & 120085 & $<$0.001 & Reject\\
Logseries & \twostack{$\alpha$}{$x$} & &&&...\\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user3579282 You are most welcome.  While thanks are appreciated, the customary way of "really" saying thanks on this site is to click the up-arrow to the left of any answer which you find "useful".  Then, as you have already done, select the "best" answer to your question by clicking the check mark.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, since I don't have enough reputation to vote up (requires 15) that's why I have chosen to say thanks in here. I will vote once I have 15 reputation!

Comment: @user3579282 It's so long ago, I forgot about such things.  Of course you are right.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to redo  the beginning of the table given as an example by the O.P., as it is more complex. I used the `booktabs`, `caption`, `makecell` and `numprint` packages, for the column for which alignment on the decimal dot makes sense. Note that whenever in such a column (of type `n{…}{…}`), a cell contains non-numeric material, it has to be enclosed between brackets.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar, noheadfoot]{geometry} 
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{heuristica} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup{labelfont = sc, labelsep = period, justification = centering }
\usepackage{makecell}

\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage[autolanguage, np]{numprint}
\usepackage{stackengine} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Chi-square analysis for data set\enspace  Total Site 1}
\begin{tabular}{c >{$}c<{$} n{2}{7}c >{$}n{1}{5}<{$} c}
\toprule\midrule
\thead{Model}  & \thead{\textbf{Parameters}} & {\thead{Estimates}} & \thead{Chi-square \\ statistics}  & \thead{\textbf{P-value}} & \thead{Outcome} \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
Geometric Series & k & 0.129202 & 17019.3 &  < 0.001 & Reject \\
\makecell*{Broken Stick \\ (binned)} & - & {\makecell{--}} & 1430.72 &  < 0.001 &     Reject \\
\makecell{Broken Stick \\ (rank abundance)} & - &  {\makecell{--}} &  120085 &  < 0.001 & Reject \\
\multirowcell{2}{Logseries}  & α &7.287017 & \multirowcell{2}{20.44702} & {\multirowcell{2}{0.11667}} & Cannot \\%
   & x  & 0.9999327 &  &  & reject \\[3pt]
\multirowcell{2}{Lognormal} & M & 6.67146 & \multirowcell{2}{30.8349} &  {\multirowcell{2}{< 0.001}} & \multirowcell{2}{Reject} \\
 & V & 16.0206 \\
 \midrule\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]